# How does ArcGIS Desktop recognize WMS CRS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, wms, gml, exogeography

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10 and working on a WMS service with Mars data. Currently the GetCapabilities shows `<SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>`. I assume ArcGIS 10 reads this and therefore the WMS has GCS_WGS_1984 as a Geographic Coordinate System?

I would like to use a custom URL definition because I am working with data from Mars. Is it for example possible to add a URL with GML such as http://spatialreference.org/ref/iau2000/49900/gml/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is no, (but I am prepared to be wrong on this), there doesn't seem to be an option to add a coordinate reference from URL, when you go into either the layer properties or the Data frame properties you can import a reference system, you can copy one from an existing  object/feature class/shape file/database or you can create your own custom one.

reading the help file from the esri website seems to indicate that you may have to do it manually,
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Setting_the_coordinate_system_of_a_WMS_service/00sp00000009000000/

or add other data which is in the coordinate system that you want first and then add the WMS which hopefully Arcmap will transform on the fly.